# Split variable length field into tuple?

Tags: python

I have a Linux shell script which output like this (Name and Score field length is variable, field seperated by spaces):

```
Name        Gender  Age Score

John Smith  M   24  1110

Alice Darby F   30  2220000
```

I want save the output into tuple so that I can sort based on different field. I just tried split with space, and joined the name field.

```
test = [('John Smith','M',24,1110),('Alice Darby','F',30,2220000)]
```

Any better method to do this?

Comment: I'd be worried about name formats, which can vary considerably.  John Q. Smith.  Alice van Darby.  Can you count on gender being either M or F?

Comment: The latter is more of a political question, though I agree it should be considered. One workaround would be to use quotes to delimit your fields in the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

If the end goal is just to sort, then use sort:

```
cat myfile.txt | tail -n+2 | grep . | sort -k2
```

That will sort by last name, if you make the assumption name is always "first last".  Adjust the sort args accordingly.